# Java - Custom JTabel show weird text

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I am making an application to show data. But it won't. I just show some weird `String`, it said `jeremy.ItemsData@33f1ca93` and another table cell show `jeremy.ItemsData@427a9389`.
Here is my code. I got the code from somewhere and I modify it because I dont want my application look like that.

```
public class JTables extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7866940189661427857L;
    public JScrollPane scroll;
    public JTable table;
    private List<ItemsData> items;

    public JTables(List<ItemsData> i)
    {
        items = i;
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI()
    {
        items.add(new ItemsData("JustTesting", null, null, null, null, null, null));

        scroll = new JScrollPane();
        table = new JTable(new JTablesModel(items));

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        table.setDefaultRenderer(ItemsData.class, new JTablesCell());
        table.setDefaultEditor(ItemsData.class, new JTablesCell());
        table.setRowHeight(292);

        scroll.setViewportView(table);

        add(scroll);
        pack();
    }
}

public class JTablesModel extends AbstractTableModel implements TableModel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3752534513457351699L;
    private List<ItemsData> item;

    public JTablesModel(List<ItemsData> i)
    {
        this.item = i;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex)
    {
        return Items.class;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column)
    {
        return "Items";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount()
    {
        return (item==null) ? 0 : item.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1)
    {
        return (item==null) ? null : item.get(arg0);
    }

}

public class JTablesCell extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, TableCellRenderer
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7826925896868335289L;
    public JLabel data;
    public JLabel icon;
    public JLabel id;
    public JLabel lvl;
    public JLabel name;
    public JLabel type;
    public JPanel p;

    public JTablesCell()
    {
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI()
    {
        p = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        icon = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        name = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        type = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lvl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        data = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        id = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        name.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        name.setText("Name");

        type.setText("Type");

        lvl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        lvl.setText("Min Lvl");

        data.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        data.setText("data");

        id.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 51));
        id.setText("Hover to view identification");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout pLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(p);
        p.setLayout(pLayout);
        pLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            pLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(pLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(pLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(pLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                        .addComponent(icon, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 64, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(44, 44, 44))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, pLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(id)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)))
                .addGroup(pLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(pLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(pLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(type, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(lvl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(data, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, pLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 127, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGap(22, 22, 22))))
        );
        pLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            pLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(pLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(pLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(pLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(name)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(type)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(lvl))
                    .addGroup(pLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(icon, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 64, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(pLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(data)
                    .addComponent(id)))
        );
    }

    private void update(ItemsData id, boolean isSelected, JTable t)
    {
        this.name.setText(id.name);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue()
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        ItemsData id = (ItemsData)value;
        update(id, true, table);
        return p;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
    {
        ItemsData id = (ItemsData)value;
        update(id, isSelected, table);
        return p;
    }

}
```

I only added I table cell but it show two. It also have some weird text on it. Can anyone improve my code so it can work better? Thanks

Comment: Isolate the problem; you posted too much code.

Comment: @NewWorld "I am making an application to show data. But it won't. I just show some weird String, it said jeremy.ItemsData@33f1ca93 and another table cell show jeremy.ItemsData@427a9389. Here is my code. I got the code from somewhere and I modify it because I dont want my application look like that."

Comment: Yes, and no one is going to read through all that code to debug your program. This is not the kind of question that gets answered on this site.

Comment: @NewWorld Well. What will you say if I didn't post any code?

Comment: Then the question would be closed for having too little to go by. As I said, isolate where in the program the problem happens then you are more likely to receive help.

Comment: @NewWorld There is not error in the console. It is just a problem of my code but I can't figure out. Just answer my question instance of talking. If you don't know how to answer just leave.

Comment: Its printing the default `toString()` implementation of Object class.

Comment: @Braj thanks :) What should I change?

Comment: @Jeremy I have posted the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution

```
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
    return (item == null) ? null : item.get(arg0).name;
}
```

---

It should be

```
item.get(arg0).name;
```

instead of

```
item.get(arg0); // It returns object to ItemsData class.
```

---

You can do in this way as well by overriding `toString()` method of `ItemsData` class as well in your existing code with `item.get(arg0);`

```
class ItemsData{

    public ItemsData(String string) {
        name = string;
    }

    public String name;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it work fine now. But as you can see, `items.add(new ItemsData("JustTesting", null, null, null, null, null, null));` there are a lot of field I want to put inside. What should I do?

Comment: One, but it have multiple row. This is what I want it to look like http://imgur.com/wd1D3ns in each row

Comment: Also, I only add 1 row. But it show 2 row with the same thing

Comment: Read more about [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Make a sample project written by you and still there is any confusion then ask a new post.

Comment: Oh do you know is that any component/library in Java so I can add multiple `JPanel` and scrollable